# What happend to a static variable that refer a gameobject when load another scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have met a problem, a static varible is refering a gameobject in a scene. When I load another scene,the static variable will be null, but the space the gameobject take up will still remain in memory,and GC dont deal with it. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> logging it returns `null`

Yes, because `UnityEngine.Object` has a [custom implementation for `ToString`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/73c12b5a403abad9a300f01a81e7aaf30a0d30b5/Runtime/Export/Scripting/UnityEngineObject.bindings.cs#L413) which returns `"null"` if the underlying object has been destroyed/unloaded.

The `c#` object instance basically still exists. Only the underlying `c++` engine object was "Destroyed" / unloaded but your `static` reference still holds a c# `GameObject`, just an invalid one. Since it is `static` the GC doesn't collect it.

If you try to access it you will see you don't get a typical expected `NullReferenceException` but rather a custom `MissingReferenceException` which is only possible since the object still exists but Unity also has a [custom implementation for `==`](https://blog.unity.com/technology/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it) which returns `true` for `someDestroyedObject == null` since again it checks for the existence of the underlying c++ instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And I use "MissingReferenceException" as keyword to search and found this blog: https://blog.unity.com/technology/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it. there is another question: Can the space that the "destroyed" object taked up be reused or not?As i think, destroy means release memory that object has took up,but untiy's profiler still show the data exist.Trank you.

Comment: @Wiseak that is the exact post I linked in my answer as well btw (the second one) ;) And as said what you "destroy" is the underlying c++ object .. the c# `GameObject` instance is still existent after that thus still been kept around in memory until you actually release it by making sure each and every reference to it is reset

Comment: As the bolg say, the c++object contains the actual informatinon,the c# object is just a wrapper with a pointer.so if you destroy the underlying c++ object ,the majoity of memory space it takes up will be release, but the unity still indicate they are occupied.Or destroying dont destroy any thing .Which is right?

Comment: Yes I would expect the major part of memory been released when you destroy the c++ object as you say .. but still the c# object stays there. So I think it depends a bit on the complexity of your object and what components and hierarchy it brings along

Comment: trank you for your help:)

Answer (score 0):

I thought garbage collection didn't collect until there were no references to the object, but your static variable is still holding the reference. It doesn't exist anymore, so it's null, but I don't think GC will collect until your static variable stops referring to it.

Comment: but if you log it, the reference  of the static variable will be null in new scene